# OnClick and Swiping Combination

Tags: android

I am trying to make a ui similar to the android camera ui. In the basic form it looks like this

[image]

I want to be able to register a click event on the button. And if the user presses down and swipes to the right it toasts showing the right textview has been selected and vice verse. The code I have at the moment looks like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener{

    private RelativeLayout overLay;
    private TextView leftTv, rightTv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        overLay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.overLay);
        leftTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.leftTv);
        rightTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rightTv);
        leftTv.setOnTouchListener(this);
        rightTv.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public void buttonOnClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "single", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "action id: " + event.getAction());
        if (v.getId() == R.id.leftTv) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.rightTv) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The 2 textviews stretch to the center of the button.

At the moment if I click the button first of all the toast for the text view which is over the button shows then the toast from the button click shows. If I click to the right of the button then swipe to the left the right toast shows.

How can I get the required results. Is there a way to detect which view the user finger is over when it is removed?

Comment: Please rephrase and explain your question clearly.. right now its very confusing to understand what you are trying to say..

Answer (score 0):

This requires gesture Listener to listen the user's touch and user releases the touch.
Here is the small [example](http://android-mantra.blogspot.in/2013/09/gallery-view-using-gestures.html) of gesture detection and action to it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Drag and Drop 
Docs
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html 
And tutorial 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gesture listener in android.

Let me explain

1.Create an abstract class OnFlingGestureListeners and implemnts **OnTouchListener**

Code sholud like this

```
public abstract class OnFlingGestureListeners implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
      gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
      return true;
  }

  private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

     private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 10;
     private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 10;
     private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;


     @Override
     public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
         if(Math.abs(e1.getY()-e2.getY())>SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
         {
             return false;
         }
        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
           onRightToLeft();
           return true;
        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
           onLeftToRight();
           return true;
        }
        if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
           onBottomToTop();
           return true;
        } else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
           onTopToBottom();
           return true;
        }

        return false;
     }

     @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         onTouchDown();
        return true;
    }




  }

  public abstract void onRightToLeft();

  public abstract void onLeftToRight();

  public abstract void onBottomToTop();

  public abstract void onTopToBottom();

  public abstract void onTouchDown();
```

}

2.Set on touch listener on your button.Its like

```
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnFlingGestureListeners() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return super.onTouch(v, event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRightToLeft() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        }

        @Override
        public void onLeftToRight() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void onBottomToTop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTopToBottom() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchDown() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

    });
}
```

And you can also use onclick listener separately.

Hope this will help